# creating a new element with addEventListener and innerHTML doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript and I can't find my mistake. I have an input field and I want to display the value entered in the input field in the section below, once the button is clicked.

I've added a click event listener on the button and tried to write a function, which would create a new p element, after the button is clicked, but that doesnt work.

```js
"use strict";

let button = document.getElementById('btn');

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let answer = document.createElement('p');
    let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    answer.innerHTML = "<p>" + input.value;
    console.log('log for testing')
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgb(149, 199, 255);
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: rgb(14, 131, 240);
    height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

h2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#input {
    display: inline;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#btn {
    font-size: 24px;
    border: none;
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#btn:active {
    background-color: rgb(201, 199, 199);
}

form {
    display: inline-flex;
}

section div {
    background-color: rgb(157, 157, 240);
    height: 100%;
    width: 444px;
    color: white;
    top: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>input to innerHTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Enter your text below</h2>
        <form id="form">    
            <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Write something here...">
            <button id="btn" type="button"> + </button>
        </form>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section>
        <div id="answer-section">
            <p></p> <!-- all the answers should go here -->
        </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody see my mistake or point me to the right direction? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You never append `answer` anywhere. `document.getElementById("answer-section").append(answer);`.

Comment: ah, such a silly mistake, but that worked! thanks!

Comment: Variable `input` is already the `value` of the element which is a string and has no more `value` property

Comment: See a tutorial: [Creating and placing new nodes](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents#creating_and_placing_new_nodes). Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). You start `answer.innerHTML` with `"<p>"`, but `answer` is already a `<p>`. [`<p>` elements](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) cannot be nested. Use `answer.textContent = input;` instead. Or: `const answer = Object.assign(document.createElement("p"), { textContent: document.getElementById('input').value });`.

Comment: thank Sebastian, will check the article.

Comment: "use strict";

let button = document.getElementById('btn');
 var input = document.getElementById('input');
 var an = document.getElementById('answer-section');
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let answer = document.createElement('p');
     let node = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    answer.appendChild(node)
    an.appendChild(answer)
 
});

Appending inside form element is not valid here.  try above thing